# Looking for a USB Mixer ROS interface

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm interested in using a Motorized USB Audio Mixer to control my ROS based system.  One example mixer would be the [Behringer BCF2000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000CZ0RJ2).  Has anyone built a ROS driver for this device or similar USB Mixer/MIDI hardware?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33234/looking-for-a-usb-mixer-ros-interface/) by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 760 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To actuate the Behringer BCF2000, have a look here:

https://kforge.ros.org/sandbox/bcf2000_driver

It's pretty similar to what was posted above. It uses pygame.midi and exposes the device with a standard Joy message. Pretty straightforward. You can listen to messages on /bcf2000/joy and write to /bcf2000/joy/input to actuate the sliders (axes) or light up the LEDs (buttons).

---

Originally posted by [jimmy.sastra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2318/jimmy.sastra/) with karma: 26 on 2012-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As kforge is no more, I quickly cooked up a new bcf2000 driver as I could not find the old one anywhere...

You can get a copy of the driver here: github.com/ihavoutis/bcf2000.git

---

Originally posted by [i.havoutis](https://answers.ros.org/users/13256/i.havoutis/) with karma: 36 on 2014-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1